# PhraseQuery is not working in Apache lucene 7.2.1

Tags: java, lucene

I am new to the Apache Lucene. I am using the Apache Lucene v7.2.1.
I need to do a phrase search in a huge file. I first made a sample code to figure out phrase search functionality in the Lucene using PhraseQuery. But it does not work.
My code is given below:

```
public class LuceneExample 
{

  private static final String INDEX_DIR = "myIndexDir";
  // function to create index writer
  private static IndexWriter createWriter() throws IOException
  {
    FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR));
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
    return writer;
  }
// function to create the index document.
  private static Document createDocument(Integer id, String source, String target)
  {
    Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new StringField("id", id.toString() , Store.YES));
    document.add(new TextField("source", source , Store.YES));
    document.add(new TextField("target", target , Store.YES));
    return document;
  }

  // function to do index search by source
  private static TopDocs searchBySource(String source, IndexSearcher searcher) throws Exception
  {        
      // phrase query build
    PhraseQuery.Builder builder = new PhraseQuery.Builder();
    String[] words = source.split(" ");
    int ii = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        builder.add(new Term("source", word), ii);
        ii = ii + 1;
    }
    PhraseQuery query = builder.build();
    System.out.println(query);
    // phrase search
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 10);
    return hits;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // create index writer
    IndexWriter writer = createWriter();
    //create documents object
    List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();

    String src = "Negotiation Skills are focused on resolving differences for the benefit of an individual or a group , or to satisfy various interests.";
    String tgt = "Modified target : Negotiation Skills are focused on resolving differences for the benefit of an individual or a group, or to satisfy various interests.";
    Document d1 = createDocument(1, src, tgt);
    documents.add(d1);

    src = "This point may benefit all of the participating entities, or just a single party, some of them, or all of them.";
    tgt = "Modified target : This point may benefit all of the participating entities, or just a single party, some of them, or all of them.";
    Document d2 = createDocument(2, src, tgt);
    documents.add(d2);

    writer.deleteAll();

    // adding documents to index writer
    writer.addDocuments(documents);
    writer.commit();
    writer.close();

    // for index searching

    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR));
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    //Search by source
    TopDocs foundDocs = searchBySource("benefit of an individual", searcher);
    System.out.println("Total Results count :: " + foundDocs.totalHits);
  }

}
```

When I searched for the string "benefit of an individual" as mentioned above. The Total Results count comes as '0' . But it is present in the document1. It would be great if I could get any help in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start from the summary:

- at index time you are using Standard analyzer with English stop words
- at query time you are using your own analysis without stop words and special characters removal

There is a rule **use the same analysis chain at index and query time**.

Here is an example of a simplified and "correct" query processing:

```
  // function to do index search by source
  private static TopDocs searchBySource(String source, IndexSearcher searcher) throws Exception {
    // phrase query build
    PhraseQuery.Builder builder = new PhraseQuery.Builder();
    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardAnalyzer().tokenStream("source", source);
    tokenStream.reset();
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
      CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
      builder.add(new Term("source", charTermAttribute.toString()));
    }
    tokenStream.end();
    tokenStream.close();
    builder.setSlop(2);
    PhraseQuery query = builder.build();
    System.out.println(query);
    // phrase search
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 10);
    return hits;
  }
```

In sake of simplicity we can remove stop words from Standard analyzer, by using constructor with empty stop words list - and everything will be simple as you expected. You can read more about stop words and phrase queries [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/phrase-Queries-a-world-without-stopwords).

All the problems with phrase queries are started from stop words. Under the hood Lucene keeps positions of all words including stop words in a special index -
 term positions. It is useful in some cases to separate "the goal" and "goal". In case of phrase query - it tries to take into account term positions. For example, we have a term "black and white" with a stop word "and". In this case Lucene index will have two terms "black" with position 1 and "white" with position 3. Naive phrase query "black white" should not match anything because it does not allow gap in terms positions. There are two possible strategies to create the right query:

- "black ? white" - uses special marker for every stop word. This will match "black and white" and "black or white"
- "black white"~1 - allows to match with gap in terms positions. "black or white" is also possible. With slop 2 and more "white and black" is also possible.

In order to create the right query you can use the following term attribute at query processing:

```
PositionIncrementAttribute positionIncrementAttribute = tokenStream.getAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);
```

I've used `setSlop(2)` in order to simplify a code snippet, you can set slop factor based on query length or put correct positions of terms in phrase builder. My recommendation is not to use stop words, you can read about stop words [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/pros-cons-stopwords.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for help and explaining It. Can you please explain that why the "builder.setSlop(3);" is used?

Comment: @priyank Yes, of course, I am still working on my answer)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. I want to do the adjact phrase match. I dont want to use the StandardAnalyzer. Can I use SimpleAnalyzer in the Lucene 7.2.1 which would simple tokenize and lowercase the sentence? I searched for SimpleAnalyzer. It is available in lower versions of Lucene (< 6) but not in lucene 7.2.1.

Comment: @priyank SimpleAnalyzer is available in analysis-common module of Lucene https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/SimpleAnalyzer.html You can add dependency on this package or create a full copy - it is very tiny and shallow analyzer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have tried it. I created IndexWriter as : "IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_7_2_1));  IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);".  But at the time of adding the documents to the writer it is giving exception as: """Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.createComponents( """ . The point of the exception is when I add the documents to the writer mentioned in following line: "writer.addDocuments(documents);".

Comment: @priyank You have an issue with your Java classpath - some libraries from Lucene 5(6) and other ones with Lucene 7. Check you dependencies and classath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164174/discussion-between-ivan-and-priyank).

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the issue. IT was related to classpath only. Thanks a lot for your help.